# Add code to a function from another function - Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function which inputs a string(e.g. type1). According to the string, it outputs a structure. However, I want to add more types(e.g. type3) to this function **from another function**.

```
function [ typeinfo ] = myType( string )
    if strcmpi('type1',string)
         typeinfo.x = 1;
         typeinfo.y = 4;
    elseif strcmpi('type2',string)
         typeinfo.x = 4;
         typeinfo.y = 1;
    end
```

In the end, I want my function myType to be:

```
function [ typeinfo ] = myType( string )
    if strcmpi('type1',string)
         typeinfo.x = 1;
         typeinfo.y = 4;
    elseif strcmpi('type2',string)
         typeinfo.x = 4;
         typeinfo.y = 1;
    elseif strcmpi('type3',string)
         typeinfo.x = 5;
         typeinfo.y = 2;
    end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Having volatile data stored in code is bad practice, use a sufficient data structure like a Map instead:

```
%just a helper for shorter code
st=@(x,y)(struct('x',x,'y',y));
%initialise the data as defined in your first function
T=containers.Map({'type1','type2'},{st(1,4),st(4,1)});
%add another type
T('type3')=st(5,3)
%get information for a type
T('type2')
```